# Defined() operator not recognized by the compiler when used with the ## operator

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, preprocessor

My purpose is to have a macro that returns a pointer to a variable (&LPUART(id)_handle) that might or might not be declared, in the latter case the pointer should be a nullptr

```
#define NUMBER_OF_UARTS defined(LPUART1_PERIPHERAL)+defined(LPUART2_PERIPHERAL)
#define GET_UART_HANDLE_POINTER(id) defined(LPUART##id##_PERIPHERAL)?&LPUART##id##_handle:nullptr
```

Problem is that the compiler throws

> error: 'defined' was not declared in this scope

this while the defined() operator is used successfully with the macro NUMBER_OF_UARTS.
**I can achieve the desired result** omitting defined()

```
#define GET_UART_HANDLE_POINTER(id) (LPUART##id##_PERIPHERAL)?&LPUART##id##_handle:nullptr
```

However I was wondering why defined does not work in the first example.

Ide: MCUXpresso IDE v11.3.0 [Build 5222] [2021-01-11]
Toolchain NXP MCU Tools
Language C++
Target Arm

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't have a ternary operator.

Comment: `defined()` is only expected to work in the context of a (preprocessor) `#if` statement, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html , so your use of it in `NUMBER_OF_UARTS` isn't checking with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor does not know anything about C and it will do the ternary operations. Also `defined()` cannot be used in this context.

To achieve this using only the preprocessor, a bit more typing is needed:

```c
#define LPUART1_PERIPHERAL ((void *)0x4567800)

#if defined(LPUART1_PERIPHERAL)
#define LPUART1_DEF 1
#define LPUART1_HND LPUART1_PERIPHERAL
#else
#define LPUART1_DEF 0
#define LPUART1_HND nullptr
#endif

#if defined(LPUART2_PERIPHERAL)
#define LPUART2_DEF 1
#define LPUART2_HND LPUART2_PERIPHERAL
#else
#define LPUART2_DEF 0
#define LPUART2_HND nullptr
#endif


#define NUMBER_OF_UARTS (LPUART1_DEF + LPUART2_DEF)
#define GET_UART_HANDLE_POINTER(id) (LPUART ## id ##_HND )


int foo()
{
    return NUMBER_OF_UARTS
}

void *bar()
{
    return GET_UART_HANDLE_POINTER(1)
}

void *zoo()
{
    return GET_UART_HANDLE_POINTER(2)
}
```

And the preprocessed code:

```c
int foo()
{
    return (1 + 0)
}

void *bar()
{
    return (((void *)0x4567800) )
}

void *zoo()
{
    return (nullptr )
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/c6shzqbcj